# Install Windows Store App itself

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-8-apps

I used to deinstall, when I set up a new Windows 8 installation, every App via Powershell by this command:

```
Get-AppxPackage | Remove-AppxPackage
```

It removed any Apps except some very basic ones e.g. the *Store App* itself.

In Windows 10, however, this command seems to remove also the Store App.
My question is how I can get it back. In the [browser store page](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/store/apps/) there is no reaction when I click on an App to install. And the store itself can't be found.

I know that there is the command `Get-AppxPackage <packagename>` but I don't know it for the store itself.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run Powershell as an Administrator

Within Powershell run `Get-Appxpackage –Allusers`
Find the entry for Microsoft.WindowsStore and copy the PackageFullName.

Run `Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.8.25.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode` but replace the item in quotes with the PackageFullName you copied in the previous step.

More [here](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-10/how-reinstall-windows-10-store).