# How to install Ubuntu on Windows 10 with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-store

With the last update of Windows 10 (Fall Creator's Update), we can install **Ubuntu on Windows**, which is a **Windows Store** application.  We can enable **Windows Subsystem for Linux** (WSL) via PowerShell with a command:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

With the spirit of *Dotfiles*, I would like to install **Ubuntu on Windows** with PowerShell.  At first hand, I thought that it could be possible with the [Appx Module](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn448373.aspx) in PowerShell.  With some experiments, it seems to apply on already installed applications.

So the question is: how to install Ubuntu on Windows 10 with PowerShell, or more generally, how to install an app from Windows Store with PowerShell?

Comment: You can’t because you have to install the Ubuntu WSL environment  from the Windows Store

Comment: Working on that. See my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/47250994/8928481

Answer (score 3):

Try this for Ubuntu:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server

Installing apps with powershell:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e5c5a26c-e8ba-439d-a0c0-074b475e0f1b/install-windows-store-apps-from-powershell?forum=w8itprogeneral

[Install Windows Store App itself](https://superuser.com/questions/983986/install-windows-store-app-itself)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people post. A part of this is including the answer in your post, [instead of simply providing a link to another page that might answer the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259). Please edit your answer to include the actual solution to the posted question. Refer to [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing) for help.