# After Windows update 1903 Sticky Notes opens in different windows

Tags: windows-10, sticky-notes, windows-10-v1903

I have a small problem with **Sticky Notes 3.6.73.0** app on **Windows 10**.

Before **1903 Update** everything was OK (all notes were in a single window). But after installing the update each note opens in new window.

How can I fix it to open new notes in a single window or even return to previous version of the app?

*After update:*

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*As you mentioned, installing the old app may be the best solution;*

1. Open Elevated Powershell [`windows key + X`, `Windows Powershell (Admin)`].
2. Remove existing app

   ```
   Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes | Remove-AppxPackage
   ```
3. Install old app (this is from my computer, if does not work review own app folder in second section),

   ```
   Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_3.1.54.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode
   ```
4. From memory you will also need to disable apps from updating, this can be done in STORE (maybe pro only) or turn off app provisioning;

   ```
   Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Where-Object {$_.PackageName -like "*StickyNotes*"} | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online
   ```

[Source One](https://superuser.com/a/984047/900431), [Source Two](https://superuser.com/a/987227/900431)

---

To review old apps:

1. Take ownership of `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` tutorial [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/access-windowsapps-folder-windows-10/).
2. Replace `Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_3.1.54.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe` of step  3 above with desired app version.

   ```
   Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\APP-NAME-HERE\AppxManifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode
   ```

Comment: I got an error after third step (after removing package): `Add-AppxPackage : Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_3.1.54.0_x64__8wekyb3d8
bbwe\AppxManifest.xml' because it does not exist.`

Comment: The solution was to remove **3.6.73** version and manually install **3.1.46** from [this website](https://www.malavida.com/en/soft/microsoft-sticky-notes/#gref)

Comment: @entithat by the way, added tutorial link to take ownership of app folder if you ever did want to install your own dated copy.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to do the following:

1. Launch the app only once
2. Open the Notes list and leave it open.
3. Close the individual notes. You can then open/close each note as needed.

Not the way I want my experience to work, but I haven't seen anything from Microsoft stating that this is a bug or even anyone else complaining.